# error: use of unstable library feature 'build_hasher_simple_hash_one'

Tags: solana-program, solana-cli

When I compile a simple hello world program, "ahash" never compiles:

```
   error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'build_hasher_simple_hash_one'
   --> src/random_state.rs:463:5
    |
463 | /     fn hash_one<T: Hash>(&self, x: T) -> u64 {
464 | |         RandomState::hash_one(self, x)
465 | |     }
    | |_____^
    |
    = note: see issue #86161 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/86161> for more information
    = help: add `#![feature(build_hasher_simple_hash_one)]` to the crate attributes to enable
For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0658`
```

In short: helloworld isn't compiling because of an unstable dependency, yet changing versions of solana-cli and/or solana-program doesn't help

Solana --version:

```
solana-cli 1.16.25 (src:8dd7d060; feat:2294205250, client:SolanaLabs)
```

Rustup --version:

```
rustup 1.26.0 (5af9b9484 2023-04-05)
info: This is the version for the rustup toolchain manager, not the rustc compiler.
info: The currently active `rustc` version is `rustc 1.75.0 (82e1608df 2023-12-21)`
```

rustup toolchain list

```
stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
solana
```

Comment: If this is your first solana program I would start with the Anchor framework

Comment: The same thing happened to me.
But, my rust is 1.75.0

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The easiest way to fix this problem is to add:

```
ahash = "=0.8.6"
```

to your dependency list in `Cargo.toml`

or run:

```
cargo update -p ahash@0.8.7 --precise 0.8.6
```

#### Error reason

The latest release of [`ahash`](https://github.com/tkaitchuck/ahash) uses [`build_hasher_simple_hash_one`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/86161) which was stabilized in `1.71` but the latest `rustc` version from the Solana tools is `1.68.0`.

Solana has its own fork of `rustc` which is on a different version than your default `rustc` installation. You can get the Solana's `rustc` version by running:

```
$ cargo build-sbf --version
solana-cargo-build-sbf 1.17.0
platform-tools v1.37
rustc 1.68.0
```

This problem will get fixed once https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/33504 is resolved.

Comment: It worked, thank you! And thanks again for the explanation, I really appreciate that!

Comment: I came across this issue when using the new `seahorse-dev` implementation. I recently updated Solana and Rust and as a result, got `ahash@0.8.7`. I downgraded to 0.8.6 using the `cargo` command.

Comment: cargo update solved it, thanks!