# Can't get solana client working

Tags: rust, solana-client

I'm running into a ton of issues with solana dependencies unfortunately.

I created a new crate with `cargo init --bin rust_client` and edited my Cargo.toml file to contain

```
[package]
name = "rust_client"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
solana-client = "1.17.15"
```

Now upon trying to `cargo build` I run into the following error:

```
error[E0423]: expected function, found macro `transmute`
   --> /.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/ahash-0.8.4/src/operations.rs:128:15
    |
128 |         xor ^ transmute::<_, u128>(vaesmcq_u8(vaeseq_u8(value, transmute!(0u128))))
    |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not a function
```

So the issue is with the ahash crate... I've tried updating it to a newer version like `0.8.6` but that just produces the following error:

```
error: failed to select a version for `ahash`.
    ... required by package `solana-frozen-abi v1.17.15`
    ... which satisfies dependency `solana-frozen-abi = "=1.17.15"` of package `solana-sdk v1.17.15`
    ... which satisfies dependency `solana-sdk = "=1.17.15"` of package `solana-client v1.17.15`
    ... which satisfies dependency `solana-client = "^1.17.15"` of package `rust_client v0.1.0 (/rust_client)`
versions that meet the requirements `=0.8.4` are: 0.8.4
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Currently using:

```
rustc 1.77.0-nightly (62d7ed4a6 2024-01-11)
solana-cli 1.17.15 (src:cc0e9a0e; feat:1237720363, client:SolanaLabs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a duplicate of [this question](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/8800/cant-build-hello-world)

These steps make it work for me on a new installation:

```
anchor init test
cd test
echo 'ahash = "=0.8.6"' >> programs/test/Cargo.toml
anchor build
```

The key is to add the line `ahash = "=0.8.6"` at the bottom of `programs/test/Cargo.toml`.

A fix is on its way but it might take a few days.

Answer (score -1):

Your version of rust should match the one here: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/rust-toolchain.toml if want to use the latest versions of these crates.

Comment: Not needed. It works fine with the version of Rust that's installed as long as they update the version of 'ahash' in their Cargo.toml.